# Saml Login Password

Tags: paw-app

We use SAML through Okta to control access to our API. We have a way to get Paw to set the cookie needed via an endpoint on our server sending our username and password. This works great, we just hit that endpoint once before and we are good to go.

The issue comes from having to store the password in Paw in the session POST body. We would like to share our paw files but it would be risky to have to remember to clear the password each time.

Is there a better approach to this? Maybe a way generate an ask user prompt?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no better way for now... What we plan to add soon is user prompt as you mentioned + storage in your machine's Keychain Access (it's a safe and encrypted mechanism handled by OS X natively).

Comment: Ok awesome. For now we may just use the "body as File" method and store credentials locally. Seems like the contents of the file aren't saved in the `.paw` file.

Comment: Yes, that's right. The File Dynamic Value (used in body as file) references to a file but never stores it in the `.paw` document.